# Intellisense doesn't reflect nullable reference types

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a C# program that targets both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 5.0 (using the `<TargetFrameworks>` element). I have enabled nullable reference types on .NET 5.0. Now I get all the nullable reference type warnings, which is what I want.

However, Intellisense doesn't appear to show the right information. For example, in .NET 5.0 `ToString()` now returns `string?`. But Intellisense shows me it returns `string`.

[image: Intellisense shows ToString() returns type string]

In addition, if I go to the definition, that also shows me it returns type `string`.

How can I have Intellisense show me the .NET 5.0 signatures?

Comment: perhaps the overload dropped it.

Comment: @DanielA.White: No, because I get a 'possible null reference return' warning if I return the result from a method marked as returning type `string`.

Comment: then thats a likely a bug. the bcl type returns non-null. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3e85099234a06ff36915b0c11289bcfe6787fc66/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Byte.cs#L167

Comment: @DanielA.White: Not according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0).

Comment: but is `value` a `System.Byte` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Byte_ToString

Comment: @JonathanWood, could you please try to remove multitargeting and leave only net5 target? Looks like we have `string` for netstandard2 and `string?` for net5. And Intellisense peek the data from netstandard.

Comment: @Serg: Yes, if I target only .NET 5.0, I see nullable reference types in Intellisense. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielA.White: You are correct. Some of the derived instances of `ToString()` return type `string`. In my example above, `value` is of type `object`. If `value` is of type `byte`, then it shows it correctly.

Comment: apparently intellisense is thinking its an `byte` variable

Comment: @DanielA.White: No, it's because I'm targeting both .NET Standard and .NET 5.0 and Intellisense is using the .NET Standard data. If I target only .NET 5.0, then it works as expected.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] - because your screenshot clearly says `value` is a `byte`

Comment: @DanielA.White: Oh, right you are. Guess I was looking at a different place in the code when I double checked. At any rate, the issue has been solved. It's due to targeting two frameworks. I guess my question now is how can I specify which framework is targeted by Intellisense.

Comment: i'd open a new question on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that while I'm targeting two versions of the framework, Intellisense picked one to get its information from. In my case, it picked the first one:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

If I change the order of the frameworks in my project file so that .NET 5.0 comes first:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Intellisense now shows me data on .NET 5.0.

So the framework used by Intellisense defaults to the first one listed. However, you can also select which framework is used from a drop down in the toolbar.

[image: Select framework used by Intellisense]